# Description of all total recursive functions where operator is effective?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory, computer-science

What is a description of all total recursive functions $g(x)$ for which the operator$$\Phi_g: \mathcal{F}_2 \to \mathcal{F}_1$$defined by the formula$$\Phi_g(f)(x) := g(\mu y(f(x, y) = 0))$$is effective?

Comment: Incidentally, this was asked at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069149/description-of-all-total-recursive-functions-where-operator-defined-by-formula-i.

Comment: Could you define your terms and notation? What is $\mathcal{F}_i$ (set of *total* functions of $i$ variables, or *partial* ones, or something else), and what does it mean for an operator to be effective?

Comment: Isn't this always effective? If I have an algorithm for $g$ and $f$, then I can compute $g(\mu y(f(x,y)=0)$ by just trying out all the $y$'s until I find one. I assume that $\mu y$ means the least one such that $f(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y')$ converges for all $y'<y$.

Comment: And if you don't have that meaning for $\mu$, but want to take just the least $y$ with $f(x,y)=0$, then the only $g$ for which the operator will be effective is when $g$ is the empty function, which never converges, since otherwise the question of the value and existence of $\mu y(f(x,y)=0)$ is not semi-computable for that interpretation of $\mu$.

Comment: I've voted to close this as unclear. I don't understand the question, and it seems others also have points of confusion.  @Andrew - you can easily edit the question to add more detail.